# Create cards dynamically in WordPress after submitting a specific form

Tags: wordpress, elementor, dinamico

I need to create a page for my collaborators which will be divided by region in which they operate and by profession.

I would like to create a form that they will fill out themselves and after sending it, personal cards will be generated in the appropriate section.
How can I do it without installing heavy plugins?

I've seen some methods around, but nothing efficient and correct.